# Play different Youtube videos on button press (Android)

Tags: kotlin, youtube, youtube-api

Suppose I have the following code:

```
 val billiejean = "B02LXuKWGTI"
 val smoothcriminal= "CBrWNbjw3RA"

 bjbutton.setOnClickListener{
    play(billiejean)
 }
 smbutton.setOnClickListener{
    play(smoothcriminal)
 }

 fun play (video:String){
    //something
 }
```

Pressing bjbutton makes the app play Billie Jean. Pressing smbutton makes the app play Smooth Criminal

What code should I put in the 'play' function? Help most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Intent that starts the video on the Youtube app, and if the app isn't installed the browser will open the link, something like this:

```
fun play(video: String) {
    val appIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:$video"))
    val webIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$video"))

    try {
        startActivity(appIntent)
    } catch (ex: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        startActivity(webIntent)
    }
}
```